# Using BeginInvoke in Web asp.net VB

Tags: vb.net, begininvoke

I am completely new in Delegate and BeginInvoke . I have a project which is written as Win form app (Vb) and now I have to change it in Web asp.net and I really dont know how I can do that:
More about my project:

when I click on run button, my project runs and it caculates some data and it shows results in some textboxes till it finished . At the End the button save data enabled in order to save Results:

See it in action:
[How the Project work](https://mega.nz/file/Pi5WwYTQ#5Ik6VPryApGM3BUEgaT6nh3HZpaW39L2JG0pVBQmKWc)

Run Button Function :

```
e.Run.Enabled = False
        Me.Run.Text = "Please wait ..."

        Me.simphony.Enabled = False
        Me.access.Enabled = False

        Me.optimizationEngineField = New OptimizationEngine(economyImportance:=0.5,
                                                            simphonyAnalysisModel:=Me.simphonyAnalysisEngine)

        Dim tempThread As New Threading.Thread(Sub()
                                                   Me.bestSolutionField = Me.optimizationEngineField.StartOptimization(percentErrorTermination:=True,
                                                                                                                       maxIteration:=CInt(Me.TextBoxMaxIteration.Text),
                                                                                                                       percentError:=CDbl(Me.TextBoxAccuracy.Text))
                                               End Sub)
        tempThread.Start()
        Me.TextBoxAccuracy.Enabled = False
        Me.TextBoxMaxIteration.Enabled = False

        Me.OptimizationStatusUpdate()

<br>
```

Optimization

```
<br>

Private Sub OptimizationStatusUpdate()
      Dim tempThread As New Threading.Thread(Sub()
                                                 Dim attempt As Integer = 0

                                                 Dim firstRun As Boolean = True
                                                 While True
                                                     If Me.optimizationEngineField.IsRunning Then
                                                         firstRun = False
                                                         Me.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                                                            Me.TextBoxStatus.Text = Me.optimizationEngineField.Status
                                                                            Me.TextBoxIsRunning.Text = Me.optimizationEngineField.IsRunning
                                                                            Me.TextBoxIterationNumber.Text = Me.optimizationEngineField.IterationNumber
                                                                            Me.TextBoxPercentError.Text = Me.optimizationEngineField.PercentError
                                                                            Me.TextBoxActiveAntCount.Text = Me.optimizationEngineField.ActiveAntCount
                                                                            Me.TextBoxAggregatedAntCount.Text = Me.optimizationEngineField.aggregatedAntCount
                                                                        End Sub)


                                                     Else
                                                         If Not Me.optimizationEngineField.IsRunning And firstRun = False Then
                                                             attempt = attempt + 1
                                                         End If
                                                         If attempt >= 5 Then
                                                             Exit While
                                                         End If
                                                     End If
                                                     Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                                                 End While
                                                 Me.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                                                    Me.ButtonSaveResults.Text = "Save Results"
                                                                    Me.ButtonSaveResults.Enabled = True
                                                                    Me.TextBoxIsRunning.Text = "False"
                                                                    Me.Run.Enabled = True
                                                                    Me.Run.Text = "Run"

                                                                    Me.simphony.Enabled = True
                                                                    Me.access.Enabled = True
                                                                End Sub)

                                             End Sub)
      tempThread.Start()
  End Sub

<br>
```

I searched a lot in net  and 
First of all : all pages approximately have been written for win apps and they are not for web , If I am not wrong and secondly : I Try to convert those codes from C# to VB and got some errors 
How can I change Optimization Code to run on Web ?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't make sense in a web app. In a WinForms app, you use `BeginInvoke` to allow you to update the UI while doing work on a secondary thread. The UI in a web app is displayed in a browser, possibly on the other side of the world. Basically, stop trying to convert the code you have and start learning how web apps work, then write appropriate code from scratch.

Comment: I have mentioned this matter and told my boss about that.. But he  insisted on displaying data on Browser and updating Textboxes synchronous

Comment: Do you mean asynchronously? There's nothing wrong with the principle but the implementation will be completely different in a web app. You would need to look into using AJAX.

Comment: yes ... Do you have any example ?

Comment: That's too broad a question for SO. You need to do some research on the topic and come back if and when you have a specific issue.

Comment: Thanks I will google it right now .... asynchronously with AJAX